# typescript set function members & using this

Tags: typescript, electron, this

I'm working on an Electron app using typescript. My main.ts creates an object of my own CommunicationProvider class. I would like to have this class declare several methods (defined in an interface it's implementing) but have the actual implementation of these methods set in my main.ts.
So I declared my class as:

```
export class SocketIOInterceptionProvider implements IInterceptionProvider {

// IInterfaceProvider methods
show: (x?: number, y?: number) => void;
hide: () => void;
move: (x: number, y: number) => void;

constructor(port: number = 3000) {

    this.initHttpServer(port);

}

public initHttpServer(port: number): void {

    this._express.get('/show', function(req, res) {
        console.log('SHOW from ' + req.ip);
        if (this.show) this.show();    
    });
}   

}
```

and in main.ts I set the implementations:

```
const provider: SocketIOInterceptionProvider = new 
SocketIOInterceptionProvider();

provider.show = (x?: number, y?: number) => { //show electron win}
```

At runtime - my function isn't triggered since 'this' is undefined, when I hit:

```
if (this.show) this.show();
```

How can I have 'this' maintained? Is there any other recommended way for handling events from a TS class?

Comment: Could you not create a local variable "this" and assign it whatever context you want?

Comment: tnx. Actually that what I did - the problem was in the express callback losing 'this', so I 'saved' this in the beginning of initHttpServer and used it for triggering the callbck.

Answer (score 1):

'this' was lost in the express callback, so I assigned it to a local variable for use in express callbacks:

```
public initHttpServer(port: number): void {

    this._express = express();
    this._httpServer = this._express.listen(port);
    const provider=this;

    this._express.get('/show', function(req, res) {
        console.log('SHOW from ' + req.ip);
        if (provider.show) provider.show();    
    });
```